# Use a XSL Variable in a XML-Tag

Tags: xslt

I have a XML File I want to transform to XML. And I need to dynamically set the name parameter of XML Tags, so it would be something like this:

```
<VALUE name="$varname"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></VALUE>
```

I got something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="PRODTABLE/PRODTR">
   <xsl:variable name="varname">
      <xsl:copy-of select="PRODTD/PRAT/@name"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <VALUE name="$varname">
      <xsl:value-of select="PRODTD/PRAT/VALUE"/>
   </VALUE>

</xsl:for-each>
```

But obviously, that doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a FAQ**.

**The quick answer**: An attribute value specified as `name="$varname"` is literally the string "$varname".

The way in XSLT to produce an attribute with a dynamically computed value is either to use AVT (**[Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)**) or the **[`<xsl:attribute>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#creating-attributes)** instruction.

**Solution**:

**Use**:

```
<VALUE name="{$varname}">
```

**Your code may be re-written in this shorter way**:

Instead of:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="PRODTABLE/PRODTR">
        <xsl:variable name="varname">
            <xsl:copy-of select="PRODTD/PRAT/@name"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <VALUE name="$varname">
            <xsl:value-of select="PRODTD/PRAT/VALUE"/>
        </VALUE>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

use:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="PRODTABLE/PRODTR">
        <VALUE name="{PRODTD/PRAT/@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="PRODTD/PRAT/VALUE"/>
        </VALUE>
    </xsl:for-each>
```